# what is the best way to rand letters for captcha with php?

Tags: php, random, captcha

What is the best way to generate random captchas to avoid the malicious robots attached?

way 1:

```
function _generateRandom( $length = 4, $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789' ) {
    return substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
}
```

way 2:

```
function _generateRandom($length=4)
{
    $_rand_src = array(
        array(48,57) //digits
        , array(97,122) //lowercase chars
        );
    srand ((double) microtime() * 1000000);
    $random_string = "";
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        $i1=rand(0,sizeof($_rand_src)-1);
        $random_string .= chr(rand($_rand_src[$i1][0],$_rand_src[$i1][1]));
    }
    return $random_string;
}
```

Or way 3...

Or not mind the random process...

I still don't know how a robot can guess the generated random words so that they can still submit the post form?

Comment: Personally, I'd go with http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: The robot guesses the CAPTCHA using OCR, not by reverse engineering your algorithm.

Comment: @Tim Cooper, what is OCR? not find in wikipedia. Thanks.

Comment: @yulichika:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Comment: Thanks for a link to reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you attach a value for CAPTCHA inside the form, the robot can read it... :)

Robots can also read an image and in some cases interpret the image into letters using a very common technique called Optical character recognition (OCR) That's why many CAPTCHAs are obfuscated and warped, to try and confused the OCR algorithms

If you want to generate random characters, here's a function of mine

```
# Generate random characters
# @param $l = length
# @param $s = use symbols?
# @param $a = use alphabetical?
# @param $n = use numbers?

function rand_chars($l=8,$s=1,$a=1,$n=1) {
  $string = ''; $chars = array();
  if ($s) $chars = array_merge($chars,array(
                     33,35,36,37,38,40,41,42,43,44,45,
                     46,47,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,91,93,
                     94,95,123,124,125,126
                     ));
  if ($a) $chars = array_merge($chars,array(
                     65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,
                     75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,
                     85,86,87,88,89,90,
                     97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,
                     107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,
                     117,118,119,120,121,122
                     ));
  if ($n) $chars = array_merge($chars,array(
                     48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57
                     ));
  for ($i=0;$i<$l;$i++) {shuffle($chars);$string.=chr(reset($chars));}
  return $string;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Robots won't guess your algorithm, but will try to read what is visible. I assume you don't echo your string, if you do, that's like having no captcha at all. Another fault that is often made, is that people load images for the generated string and name (or alt) the image the exact same as the distorted character that represents it. That wouldn't do well either.